# How to declare a static variable globally?

Tags: c#, static, global-variables, runtime

I have created a static class and static variable in one of the startup project from the solution. And I am changing the value if users enter any value from the UI, which logic is written in another one startup project in the solution. So the problem here is, When I access the static variable's value from the different startup project, then the value/data of the static variable is not same or fetching the previously assigned value.

My Static class,

```
namespace Platform.Models
{
   public static class PlatformConstants
   {
      public const string DefaultLogLevelValue = "Debug";
   }
}
```

Assigning value from UI or Model,

```
namespace Platform.Services.Data {
.....
PlatformConstants.DefaultLogLevelValue = incomingModel.LogLevel.Trim();
```

Fetching data to check log level,

```
public static string LogLevelThreshold
{
     get { return PlatformConstants.DefaultLogLevelValue; }
}
```

What is wrong here, Why I am not able to get the last assigned value from other project ?

(Example: Consider A & B projects and Default value is "Warn". Now I am assigning the value "Error" from A project. If I get the static variable value from project A means its "Error" but the value is "Warn" if i get the value from B project. Where I did go wrong here?.)

Comment: That code doesn't compile, you cannot change a `const` field. Also, you cannot just open two applications and expect them to be able to read each other's data. You need an inter-process way of communicating if you want shared state

Comment: @Camilo, I did not use any constant variable here and not able to ready each other's data means, then why the different value is coming here? Do you have any idea? Or can you elaborate your answer little more?  Static variable in a static class will be always same for the entire solution right?

Comment: _I did not use any constant variable_ Sure ?  `public const string DefaultLogLevelValue`

Comment: Yes I am sure. I didn't use any constant variable like const or readonly and all.

Answer (score -1):

To set value on every project, it's more appropriate to use getter-setter.
Indeed a constant has for use not to be modified

Try to use getter setter with a default value like this :

```
    public string DefaultLevelValue { get; set;  } ="Debug";
```

And you set your value with user interface :

```
    DefaultLevelValue =  incomingModel.LogLevel.Trim();
```

And you'll can get the right value !

Comment: -1? WTF. Read MSDN doc. Modify a constant ? mdr. https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const